# Navigation between the screens in android

Tags: android, start-activity

In my application consider i am having 2 screens screen A and screen B.In screen A i have 2 edit boxes and 1 spinner,When coming first time the screen will not show the 2 edit boxes.And if user selects any value from spinner it will go to screen B,in that i am getting some values from user and if user clicks OK it will come to Screen A.Now it should show the 2 edit boxes.SO i done startactivityforresult ,but it is not coming into that part.Please help me.Thanks in advance.

My coding:

screen B:

```
 ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
            {               
                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0)
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),BudgetJulyo4Activity.class);                       
                    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);

                }
            });
```

Screen A:

```
  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
        {
            // Result OK.d.
            System.out.println("Inside start");      -------------->This line is not printing.SO what i am doing wrong.
            if (requestCode == 1)
            {
                // do something good
                System.out.println("Inside start if");
                 EditText date=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.startdate);
                EditText NoOfRecc=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);

                date.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                NoOfRecc.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for down voting person..Can u please tell y u down voted this question??So that i will not repeat the same in my future post..

Answer (score 0):

While I can't see the rest of your code, what you have posted looks ok, your on the right lines. However, startActivityForResults() is an underlying activity function that you need to override. Altering your call to the following should mean it gets called.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent)
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);

    // Result OK.d.
    System.out.println("Inside start");      -------------->This line is not printing.SO what i am doing wrong.
    if (requestCode == 1)
    {
            // do something good
            System.out.println("Inside start if");
             EditText date=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.startdate);
            EditText NoOfRecc=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);

            date.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            NoOfRecc.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Richard Lewin..But still the problem..I placed the above code after oncreate() of screen A.Is it correct??

Comment: Prakash, I have just re-looked at your question and you are intimating you have the srtartActivityForResult() call in screen B and the onActivityResult in screen A. If this is the case it will not work. startActivityForResult() and onActivityResult() must be in the same activity (same screen).

Comment: Use the startActivityForResult() call in screen A to launch screen B. Then when returning to screen A from Screen B it will be fired.

Comment: Richard Lewin...Still having that problem...Richard Lewin as i explained my scenario in my post is any other way to do that???

Comment: if on screen B you are showing screen A via a new intent don't. Try calling finish() in the button onClickListner in screen B. I.e. @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0)
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    finish();

                }

Comment: Its not possible Richard Lewin..Then the edit boxes will never come for all scenario..

Comment: You said you want to show the Edit boxes after the first load yes? I.e. only once the user has come back from screen B. If this is correct hiding them in the layout first will mean they won't show up. Then use the onActivityResult() when coming back from screen B to show them via making the visible in code. Sorry to say, but I have helped you as far as I can based on the information in your question as you have not gone into enough detail as to what you want to achieve.

Comment: Thats what i am doing Richard Lewin..K Richard Lewin i will explain my scenario clearly..When 1st coming into the app in screenA it should not show the edit boxes(thats happening means working correctly).If user selects any value from spinner it goes to screenB.In that i am getting some date and another 1 field.I have to show this 2 data in screenA when user clicks ok in screenB.I think i have explained clearly...

Comment: Ok, first I will say again, using the finish command in screen B means the onActivityResult() should fire in screen A if startActivityForResult() was used to start screen B. Secondly, to pass data back you will want to add data to the intent before ending screen B via: Intent data = new Intent();
data.putExtra("message", "I'm comming back!");      
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, data);

Comment: Thanks Richard Lewin.If i use finish() means.it helped in some other logic,not in this way..But i think i achieved my result...thanks a lot...